# memory segmentation in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm having a trouble while working on a homework. I am preparing a little project about linked lists.
I wrote a program which shows me an error message about segmentation fault. I've no Idea , what does this stuff mean and what have I to do.
I'm looking forward to recieving some solution from you guys
here is the code

```
‪#‎include‬ <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct Data{
int numero;
char *prenom;
float taille;
}donnees;
typedef struct list linked_list;
struct list{
donnees *data;
linked_list *next;
};
int main(){
int taille,i;
linked_list *tete,*ptr,*tete1;
tete=ptr=NULL;
printf("\nentrer le nombre des etudiants a introduire dans la liste :   ");
scanf("%d",&taille);
for(i=0;i<taille;i++){
ptr=(linked_list*)malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
printf("\nentrer le numero de l'etudiant :");
scanf("%d",&(ptr->data->numero));
printf("\nentrer le nom de l'etudiant :");
scanf("%s",(ptr->data->prenom));
printf("\nentrer le numero de l'etudiant :");
scanf("%f",&ptr->data->taille);
ptr->next=NULL;
if(tete==NULL)tete=ptr;
else{
ptr->next=tete;
tete=ptr;
}
printf("votre liste s'ecrit sous la forme :\n[tete]->");
ptr=tete;
while(ptr!=NULL){
printf("[ %d - %s -%f ]->",ptr->data->numero,ptr->data->prenom,ptr-  >data->taille);
}
printf("NULL\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand your own code? From a quick glance, it seems that you have a bad pointer.

Comment: Please indent your code. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't understand code formatted like that either.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand the *language* (used in variable naming and print statements), but it seems

```
 scanf("%d",&(ptr->data->numero));
```

is the problem. You need to allocate memory to `ptr->data` before dereferencing it.

To explain, `data` is also a pointer. You need to allocate memory [`malloc()`] to it before using it, just like you did for `ptr`.

same case is applicable for

```
scanf("%s",(ptr->data->prenom));
```

here, you need to allocate both `data` and `prenom` before using.

Also, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Good one, I don't understand the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&(ptr->data->numero));
```

You never allocated memory for `data`.

```
scanf("%s",(ptr->data->prenom));
```

You never allocated memory for `prenom`.

Use `malloc` as you did for `ptr` to allocate memory for these objects.